# How to find touch on UIwindow?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitouch, uiwindow

i have four viewcontroller in my UIwindow.i want to interchange my viewcontroller's view among four through UItouch in UIWindow?is it possible to handle touchmoved in appdelegate.m file to change the frame origins of those viewcontrollers?

Answer (score 1):

A UIWindow is the parent class of a UIControl (which is what receives touch events) so it cannot handle touch events.  You should put one master VC as a subview to the UIWindow, and then use that VC to exchange the subsequent VC's and views.

Comment: I don't disagree with your approach using one view controller to manage subviews, but the justification is incorrect. It *is* possible to capture touches in a `UIWindow` subclass. `UIWindow` inherits from `UIView`, not `UIControl`. `UIView` is derived from `UIResponder`. In other words, if you *really* wanted, you *could* subclass `UIWindow` and capture UI events before they're forwarded to your view.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `UIGestureRecognizer` (`UIPanGestureRecognizer` among them) to **any view** handle the action **from any other object** using the gesture's:

```
- (id)initWithTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action;
```